# phonegap installation error ".cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create.bat: Com mand failed with exit code 8"

Tags: android, cordova

I got the following Error with my phonegap installation:

> [phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment... 
>     [phonegap] using the local environment
>     [phonegap] adding the Android platform...
>
> C:\Users\dr170.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
>                       throw e;
>                             ^ Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
>       at C:\Users\dr170.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:8
>   7:29
>       at _rejected (C:\Users\dr170.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_mod
>   ules\q\q.js:808:24)
>       at C:\Users\dr170.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js
>   :834:30
>       at Promise.when (C:\Users\dr170.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_
>   modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\dr170.cordova\lib\android\cord
>   ova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
>       at C:\Users\dr170.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js
>   :574:44
>       at flush (C:\Users\dr170.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules
>   \q\q.js:108:17)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13) { [Error: C:\Users\dr170.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create.bat: Comm
>   and failed with exit code 8] code: 8 }    [error]
>   C:\Users\dr170.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create.bat: Com
>   mand failed with exit code 8

Do you have any suggestions for me ?

Comment: make sure your SDK and ANT path are in your environment variables

Comment: Make sure you set the path of your sdk and also install the required targets in your SDK manager.I think cordova 3.4 uses target 19